# NoException in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Cassandra hector API

Tags: exception, client, cassandra, nosuchmethoderror

i'm trying to install and  execute the cassandra API : hector.

During the launch of the process, 1 exception is throw and  this trace appear :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Column.(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;J)V
>       at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.HColumnImpl.toThrift(HColumnImpl.java:112)
>       at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.addInsertion(MutatorImpl.java:98)
>       at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.insert(MutatorImpl.java:54)
>       at com.featherlite.example.dao.ObjectDAO.insert(ObjectDAO.java:87)
>       at com.featherlite.example.ClientExample.testWR(ClientExample.java:148)
>       at com.featherlite.example.ClientExample.main(ClientExample.java:225)

I just launch an project from the example. I didnt write this i just try.

I already saw it happens when i load 2 different or an old thrift jar library. 
In my project, there are 2 thrifts jar files :

- libthrift-0.7.0.jar
- apache-cassandra-thrift-1.1.0.jar

The first is the jar concerning with this exception because when i delete him, i have more erors.

Apache Cassandra : 1.1.0

Sorry for my bad english :/

kinds regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apache-cassandra-thrift-1.1.0.jar contains Cassandra's Thrift-related classes, while the libthrift-0.7.0.jar is the underlying Thrift protocol implementation.  Sounds like you may have an old jar being referenced in your classpath, perhaps being loaded with higher precedence?

Comment: thanks for your response rs_atl. 
I try to deleting libthrift.0.7.jar,when i'm launch my projet, i get and new exception but not away from the first :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.KsDef.<init>

Comment: Both jars are required, so you can't delete either of them.  Either way it's pretty clear you have a jar version issue somewhere.  What Hector version are you using?

Comment: my version of Hector is : 0.7.0.22 (the lastest i think). I have the same thrift jars in Hectorclient project and in my project. 
strange situation ..
and more, i see the KSDEF method in apache-cassandra-thrift-1.1.0.jar ....

Comment: That's not the latest Hector. I am using 1.0-2 from maven against Cassandra 1.1 with no problems. 1.0-5 is the latest, and 0.7 is actually quite old.  This is very likely your issue.

Comment: Hum actually, my version is 1.0.3 not 0.7.22 (was looking wrong file). no others ideas to resolve it ?

Comment: Put just the cassandra, thrift, and hector jars in a directory, then write a simple class in a text editor that does a basic read or write.  Compile with javac, specifying the jar directory as classpath.  Run it with the java command.  This will take your IDE and project out of the equation and just test the compatibility of the jar files.